# Imagine having a broken radio transmitter, and I need to make it work by building a solenoid with an inductance of 100 uH. How can I do it?

Tags: radio, inductance, solenoid

This is a problem made by my professor.

Imagine having to repair a radio in a rural area, without any high-tech instruments, and I need to build a solenoid with an inductance of 100uH, a cross-section area of 1.00 cm2 and a lenght of 3.00cm.

Do I need to find the number of turns and their diameter, explaining also the type of material I would use?

I found some formulas, such as L  = [d2 n2] / [18d + 40l] , or this L = u0 * (n2/l) * S . What's the difference between them?

https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2014/03/inductance-air-core-inductor-calculator.html (This is the link to the first formula, while the second one was found in my physics' course book).

I know that I have to find the number of turns and their diameter, the only thing I don't know is which formula do I have to use.

Comment: And you want an inductor, not a solenoid. A solenoid is an actuator, usually a type of linear motor with a coil and a moving core.

Comment: Try to find the equations for inductance of an air-cored inductor on a web search. [Edit] them into your question and do some calculations and we'll help you out. Give a guess at what would be suitable materials and where you might find them out in the country.

Comment: Please give us links to the places where you found these formulas, and explain what the variables are. Since this is a classwork problem we will expect you to do most of the real work and only ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: It’s not about memorizing the right formula, but understanding the theory and physics behind it to solve the problem.

Comment: If both formulas are a good approximation, then they should both give about the same answer.  In which case it won't matter which one you use.  Have you tried putting in values into both formulas to compare them?

Comment: @Transistor: in physics terminology, a "solenoid coil" is a simple coil.  So "solenoid" is a valid term.  Even if the word "solenoid" is usually applied to the actuator.

Comment: If you're going to give an equation like \$L = \mu_0 \frac{n^2}{l} S\$, then **define your terms** -- in particular, what is \$S\$?  (And if you want a deep dive -- this site supports MathJax, so you can write the LaTeX as \\$L = \mu_0 \frac{n^2}{l} S\\$).

Comment: @Tim, you're right, I'm wrong. Solenoid can refer to a simple coil.